# Flash using too much ram in firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, memory, flash

As far as I know I have the latest version of flash (I updated a couple days ago). For at least the last month I have noticed flash using far too much ram (between 200 and 500 MB). I notice it because my computer will stutter, and then it will resume fine after killing Flash's process. Its typically caused by a popunder ad with a lot of flash on it.

Right now, it has spiked out of control. It is using **2 gigs** of RAM. I have 7 tabs open and no popunders. It used to be that upgrading flash would fix this type of error, but it hasn't. I have to kill flash it seems like almost every half hour during a normal browsing session. Has anyone else seen a spike in Flash's usage? I have a decent machine (8 gb of ram, Samsung 840 SSD, and Intel 3840QM@2.7Ghz) and this makes firefox unusable and also slows down other programs. **Is there a permanent solution to prevent flash from monopolizing my system during an average, modest browsing session?**

[image]

Comment: You have 8 gigs of RAM and only 50% of it is in use. I don't see how this is bringing your computer to its knees. If it eventually takes up all RAM on the system or if the process is orphaned, just talk to the folks at: https://forums.adobe.com/

Comment: Spiking ram usage is often a crash waiting to happen, fixing it early is smart.

Comment: @Tyler you're right, its really just firefox that it screws up, I've edited

Comment: Ahh, in that case, maybe check out this article: [Firefox Uses too Much Memory-RAM](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-ram). They recommend disabling hardware acceleration as @vembutech suggests. It might also help to tell us what websites you are visiting. They may be poorly coded or memory-intensive sites. You could also use a plugin like [FlashBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/) or [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) to make flash load on demand.

Comment: @Tyler I'm trying a flash blocker as suggested by Xen2050. I'll check back in after using it for a bit, but it looks promising. All seems so obvious now!

Comment: Permanent solution?  Don't use flash.  Make sure you have the latest plug-ins for all your browsers too.  Also, make sure you are running the latest version of firefox!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Firefox open `about:config`, type `plugin.state.flash` in the search and set the value to `1`. Now Firefox asks you every time if it should enable Flash for a website or not. So Flash should run less often and you should not see the issue so often. Also report it in the Adobe Forums.

Comment: This was the best option for me, I activate the ones I want and am not even aware most of the time of the ones I don't. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**In this case,** First Clear your recent history and also  you can try disabling the Hardware Acceleration in Flash Player

**Please find the steps below:**

1. Navigate to the Adobe Flash Player Help page
2. Right click on the Flash Player logo.
3. And then go to Settings in the context Menu and click the icon at the bottom-left of the Adobe Flash Player Settings window to open the Display panel.
4. Remove the check mark from Enable hardware acceleration.
5. Restart Fire Fox.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could look for **[flash blocking add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/search/?q=flash%20block)** (not just hiding with flash still running) or **[click-to-play add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/search/?q=click%20to%20play)**.

Or downgrade flash back to the version that worked better. Then later, when there's a newer update, give it a try?